# count the number of occurrences of "(" in a string

Tags: r, stringr

I am trying to get the number of open brackets in a character string in R. I am using the `str_count` function from the `stringr` package

```
s<- "(hi),(bye),(hi)"
str_count(s,"(")
```

> Error in stri_count_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = attr(pattern,
>       : `   Incorrectly nested parentheses in regexp pattern.
>       (U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN)

I am hoping to get 3 for this example

Comment: escape it `str_count(s,"\\(")`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`(` is a special character. You need to escape it:

```
str_count(s,"\\(")
# [1] 3
```

Alternatively, given that you're using `stringr`, you can use the `coll` function:

```
str_count(s,coll("("))
# [1] 3
```

Answer (score 5):

You could also use `gregexpr` along with `length` in base R:

```
sum(gregexpr("(", s, fixed=TRUE)[[1]] > 0)
[1] 3
```

`gregexpr` takes in a character vector and returns a list with the starting positions of each match. I added fixed=TRUE in order to match literals.`length` will not work because `gregexpr` returns -1 when a subexpression is not found.

---

If you have a character vector of length greater than one, you would need to feed the result to `sapply`:

```
# new example
s<- c("(hi),(bye),(hi)", "this (that) other", "what")
sapply((gregexpr("(", s, fixed=TRUE)), function(i) sum(i > 0))
[1] 3 1 0
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it in base R you can split into a vector of individual characters and count the `"("` directly (without representing it as a regular expression):

```
> s<- "(hi),(bye),(hi)"
> chars <- unlist(strsplit(s,""))
> length(chars[chars == "("])
[1] 3
```

Comment: or this `nchar(s) - nchar(gsub('\\(', '', s))` for base R