# count number of digits in a string in r

Tags: r

I have a column with strings:

```
name
aldrinas63_rios200_2001
sa_c.fr.1234
```

I want to count the number of digits in each cell: I have used the following code:

```
str_count(data$name, '\\d+')
```

But I have getting the output as:

```
Name                    output_I_get
aldrinas63_rios200_2001  3
sa_c.fr.1234             1
```

But my desired output is as follows:

```
name                     output
aldrinas63_rios200_2001   9
sa_c.fr.1234              4
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated!

Comment: see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42394489/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-in-a-string) using `str_count` from the `stringr` package.

`str_count('\\d', c(data$name))`

Comment: So you can conclude from @akrun's answer that the plus sign in `'\\d+'` is the cause of your error. Try it without it.

Comment: When you are using `str_count(data$name, '\\d+')` you are counting how many [multi-digit] numbers there are. If you do `str_count('200', '\\d+')` the answer is 1 [multi-digit] number. If you do `str_count('200', '\\d')` the answer is 3 single-digits.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We can remove the elements that are not digits and count

```
nchar(gsub("[^0-9]+", "", data$name))
#[1] 9 4
```

---

or if we are using `str_count`, remove the `+` as `+` checks for patterns of one or more digits and count `63` as first instance, `200` as second, and `2001` as third (for the first element of 'name')

```
library(stringr)
str_count(data$name, "[0-9]")
#[1] 9 4
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(name = c("aldrinas63_rios200_2001", "sa_c.fr.1234"
 )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
nchar(gsub("\\D", "", data$name))
```

Example

```
s <- c("aldrinas63_rios200_2001","sa_c.fr.1234")

nchar(gsub("\\D", "", s))
#[1] 9 4
```